# Javascript expand the sort order of an array to another array of same size

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays

```
[10,8,0,5,3]
[2,4,1,1,3]
```

I would like to sort the first array to decreasing order, so it becomes `[10,8,5,3,0]`. The first array's original indices `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` after sorted becomes `[0, 1, 3, 4, 2]` for example, the original number `5` was in 3rd index, after sorted, it comes to the `2` index. Now, I would like to apply the sorted index to the second array `[2,4,1,1,3]`, so it becomes `[2, 4, 1, 3, 1]` Is there a quick and easy way to do it?

I came up with 2 solutions so far:

1. construct an object that holds the key value pair, with the keys being the values of the first array, and values are the second array, for example

```
{'10': 2, '8': 4, '0': 1, '5': 1, '3':3 }`
```

Then sort the object according to the key values. Then the values will be sorted, then retrieve all the values from the object.

2. Construct a map with the values of the first array pointing to each of the values of the second array. Sort the map, and retrieve each value.

These two methods seem a bit complicated. I am wondering if there is an easier way such as leverage the array.sort() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you zip the arrays together into a single array, where each item contains the `i`th value from both arrays, you can sort that larger array pretty easily:

```js
const arr1 = [10,8,0,5,3];
const arr2 = [2,4,1,1,3];
const zipped = arr1.map((num, i) => [num, arr2[i]]);
zipped.sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0]);
console.log(zipped.map(arr => arr[0]));
console.log(zipped.map(arr => arr[1]));
```

Comment: Is this more performant than the object or map approaches that I was doing?

Comment: Your first approach will require creating an unnecessary object before transforming it into an array of entries for sorting. (Also keep in mind that object keys can't be sorted in the case of numeric array indicies like we have here.) Your second approach similarly requires an unnecessary data construct before transforming it into an array afterwards, I think (though I'm not sure exactly what you're thinking of there).

Comment: Still, performance isn't much of an issue. The more important thing is how easy the code is to read and understand, which I think sorting a zipped array qualifies for.